# Change Value of dynamic keys of array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have an dynamic array consisting of dynamic keys. I want to check if any of these keys have null values then it would be change to 0. any Idea thanks in advance
Sample Array

```
   array (
      'empid' => string 'UPW_OB_8' (length=8)
      'TotalLoginHrs' => string '0' (length=1)
      'status' => string 'id not used' (length=11)
      '20140401' => 1
      '20140402' => null
      '20140403' => 2
      '20140404' => null
      '20140405' => 1
      '20140406' => null
      '20140407' => 9
      '20140408' => null
      '20140409' => 3
      '20140410' => null
      '20140411' => 5
      '20140412' => null
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `preg_replace` to find the null values:

```
$replaced = preg_replace("/^$/u", "0", $array);
```

example: **https://ideone.com/j0j9IZ**

Answer (score 1):

you need to check for it and assign 0 value

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if (is_null($value)) {
         $array[$key] = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[array_walk](http://php.net/array_walk)

```
array_walk($fruits, function(&$item,$key){
    if (is_null($item)) $item = 0;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
$array = array_map(function($value){
    return (is_null($value)) ? "" : $value;
},$array)
```